# How do you find the dinero.js currency from its code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dinero.js

I want to find the dinero currency in the `dinero.js/currencies` package from its code. What is the simplest way to do it?

Like having a function `getCurrency` that takes a string as an input and returns the right dinero currency.

Comment: I see in the documentation a function to getCurrency. Is this what you are looking for? https://dinerojs.com/module-dinero#~getCurrency

Comment: No, it returns the currency of a dinero object. I want to find a currency from its code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to import all the currencies and to find the right module from its name.

```
import * as currencies from '@dinero.js/currencies';

const currencyCode = 'USD';
const dineroCurrency = currencies[currencyCode];
```